# Codeigniter replace uploaded image

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload, avatar

I'm using Codeigniter's [File Uploading Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for uploading user avatars. Is there a way to replace a user's image file whenever he/she uploads a new one? I want to replace an existing avatar with the newest one uploaded.

My image uploading controller

```
function upload_avatar()
    {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/avatars/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png';
        $config['overwrite'] = FALSE; //overwrite user avatar
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = '200'; //in KB

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors(); 

            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', $error);

            redirect('/settings/avatar');
        }
        else
        {                
            $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $config['source_image'] = $this->upload->upload_path.$this->upload->file_name;
            $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
            $config['width'] = 120;
            $config['height'] = 120;

            $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

            $this->image_lib->crop();

            //Add image path to database
            $avatar_path = 'uploads/avatars/' . $this->upload->file_name;
            $user_id = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();
            $this->Settings_model->update_avatar($avatar_path, $user_id);

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Avatar updated!');

            redirect('/settings/avatar');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried setting this line `$config['overwrite'] = FALSE; //overwrite user avatar` to `TRUE`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a public attribute `overwrite` that dictates the decision to overwrite the original file.  By default, a new filename is created based on the original.  Here's the source from Upload.php in CI:

```
/*
 * Validate the file name
 * This function appends an number onto the end of
 * the file if one with the same name already exists.
 * If it returns false there was a problem.
 */
$this->orig_name = $this->file_name;

if ($this->overwrite == FALSE)
{
    $this->file_name = $this->set_filename($this->upload_path, $this->file_name);

    if ($this->file_name === FALSE)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

So all you need to do to get the overwrite working is:

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->overwrite = true;
```

Comment: Thanks! For the replace to work I reckon that I'll have to give each avatar image a unique name like the user's username. This way anything a user uploads replaces what's already stored.

Answer (score 5):

Simple set "overide" be true in your config.

```
$this->upload->initialize(array(
            "upload_path"=>$path,
            "allowed_types"=>"jpg|png|jpeg",
            "overwrite"=>true
        ));
```

Answer (score 3):

did you try to change

```
$config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
```

to

```
$config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: A good alternative compared to `$this->upload->overwrite = true;`